# google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 9:18 : Couldn't parse integer: 03

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow, video-processing, object-detection-api

Im using python 3.6 tensorflow 1.5
im following the link

But got the error:

doe@doe:~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/doe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:124: main (from **main**) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1500, in _ParseAbstractInteger
    return int(text, 0)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 0: '03'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1449, in _ConsumeInteger
    result = ParseInteger(tokenizer.token, is_signed=is_signed, is_long=is_long)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1471, in ParseInteger
    result = _ParseAbstractInteger(text, is_long=is_long)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1502, in _ParseAbstractInteger
    raise ValueError('Couldn\'t parse integer: %s' % text)
ValueError: Couldn't parse integer: 03

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in 
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/doe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/doe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 136, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 93, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "/home/doe/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 94, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 536, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 590, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 623, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 638, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 763, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 837, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 763, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 837, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 763, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 871, in _MergeScalarField
    value = _ConsumeInt32(tokenizer)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1362, in _ConsumeInt32
    return _ConsumeInteger(tokenizer, is_signed=True, is_long=False)
  File "/home/doe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1451, in _ConsumeInteger
    raise tokenizer.ParseError(str(e))
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 9:18 : Couldn't parse integer: 03

Comment: sorry the link was:  https://becominghuman.ai/tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-training-and-evaluating-custom-object-detector-ed2594afcf73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem relating to label_map_path when running on local machine. Solved by removing spaces between lines in the label map pbtxt file. Please check config file as well.

Comment: Thanks...I got my error corrected. The problem was on the config file.